# How to stop overwriting x-amz-website-redirect-location metadata

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

I have a website with some pages set with a permanent redirect setup using `x-amz-website-redirect-location` within Amazon S3.

The issue I have is whenever I upload changes the metadata is overwritten.

Is there a way to set this metadata within HTML? Lock the files to not change metadata or a way to sync without losing this metadata?

Comment: It is lost because when you upload changes you are actually deleting the old object and replacing it. You can specify metadata on upload.

Comment: @jordanm Do you mean having to manually specify the metadata for each file every time an upload is done, that seems tedious? Is there no other alternative?

Comment: You could setup a lifecycle hook that triggers a lambda which re-uploads your file on upload with the desired metadata.